# Maven optional repository

Tags: maven-2

I am converting a project to use Ant/maven-ant-tasks. I have a local repository in $HOME/.m2, an enterprise repository on a local machine on the LAN, and I have listed several global repositories (http://repo2.maven.org/, etc.).

If I am out of the office, is there a way to have Maven skip the enterprise repository in it searching for dependency resolutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by swiching profiles :

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>atWork</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                ...
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>atHome</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                ...
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

If you're "at home" you can activate your home profile and deactivate the "at work" profile.

You can use this either in your pom.xml (not recommended) or in your ~/.m2/settings.xml (recommended)

---

**Resources :**

- [Maven - profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)
- [Maven - settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

Comment: +1 this would work for repositories indeed. I wish there was some kind of network based activation thing.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no particular facility for this in Maven (something like network based settings). If you only need to manage repositories, you can do it with profiles as suggested by [@Colin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3842401/maven-optional-repository/3842488#3842488). If you need to manage mirror definitions (that you can't declare inside profiles) you are screwed and you'll need to use different `settings.xml`, or to edit it, or to script the change. You might want to track [MNG-3525](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3525). See also the related question below.

#### Related question

- [Make Maven Proxy/Server settings configurable based on location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354001/make-maven-proxy-server-settings-configurable-based-on-location)