# Maven proxy settings, work vs home

Tags: maven, proxy

I work off a laptop, and when I'm at work I have to go through a proxy to resolve Maven dependencies. When I'm at home this fails, so I need to disable it. Is there a way to get this to work in the [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) so I don't have to manually disable/enable this all the time?

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354001/make-maven-proxy-server-settings-configurable-based-on-location?rq=1 which is the identical question, pretty much

Answer (score 1):

You can set up profiles in your settings.xml to control this; see http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Profiles.

You will have to control this with *some* external information though.  How can you detect which network you're on?  You can always supply a variable using environment, or a -P option, but you would still have to set something.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the plug, but I've just released the source code of a Maven plugin that enables automatic proxy discovery in Maven: https://github.com/volkertb/autoproxy-maven-plugin

The goal is to be able to roam between networks using Maven without having to edit any static proxy settings in settings.xml manually. This is a first version, so you might run into some bugs if you use it. If you do, please let me know. I hope this is useful to you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for inspiring setting proxy via plugin.

I created a plain non-autodetect plugin to set in memory the proxy settings to the desired configuration, which needs to be specified in the configuration section of my plugin, see https://github.com/c-a-services/overwrite-proxy-setting-plugin